# How to access one column related to another table Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have 3 models, Trials has one sample and track has one trial, I need to access sample name, I try to do this but get this error:

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2024: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::samples()

**Controller:**

```
public function track($id){
        $tracks = track::with('trials')->with('samples')->where('trials_id',$id)->get();

        return view('Tracks.index',compact('tracks'));
    }
```

**Samples:**

```
class samples extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['variety'];

    public function Trials()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\trial');
    }
```

**Trial:**

```
class trial extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['amount','date','comments','code'];

    public function Samples()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\samples', 'id', 'samples_id');
    }

    public function Track()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\track');
    }
}
```

**Tracks:**

```
class track extends Model
{
    public function Trials()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\trial', 'id', 'trials_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: **samples()** method is not define in **track** model.

Comment: This mean I need to add another foreign key to track table to related to samples ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
$tracks = track::with('trials.samples')->where('trials_id',$id)->get();
```

Ref:- [Nested Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: `with('trials.samples')` will load trials and trials.samples, dont need the other `with('trials')`.